# Open a specific url by typing a single letter in the address bar in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'd like to open a specific URL by typing a single letter in the address bar of google chrome. Before, when I typed the letter "g", google wrote automatically the URL.
Now I deleted the cache, so google forgot the memory.

I tried to open many times the following URL (google books in which I set specific parameters: book, from 1980 to today, view and preview), but google is not able to memorize it.
Is there a way to do it?

https://www.google.com/search?q=permanent+magnets&biw=1844&bih=859&tbs=bkv%3Ap%2Cbkt%3Ab%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1980&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsavxN81sUhg1u3zEiihlJCme8Kq7g%3A1665304163054&ei=Y4ZCY4vvApOCxc8P3uqDiAQ&ved=0ahUKEwjLrNO43dL6AhUTQfEDHV71AEEQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=permanent+magnets&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABFAAWOISYLITaABwAHgAgAHEAYgB5wySAQQxNS4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps below:

1. Open Settings -> Search engines -> Manage search engines and site search -> Site Search,  click <kbd>Add</kbd>.
2. Enter the Search engine name (even of the site is not a search engine). Enter the shortcut, then the site's URL. Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
3. On the address bar, type the shortcut created on the previous step, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The URL entered on step 2 will open.

[image]